# Embedded view with documents corresponding to document in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula, notesview

do you have a idea how can I solve this in Lotus Notes?

1. There is a document Form Person.

In this document I want to have a embedded view that shows notes only related to this person.

2. I created a Form Notes and a view Notes. I can embed the view in the Person mask and select a view. In my case Notes.

The problem is that I see all notes for all persons. Not only the notes to this person where the view is embedded.

How can I refer to only the current Person document?
How can I build a button in the embedded view to create a new notes document that refers to the current person document where the embedded view actually is?

Thanks!

Best regards
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a formula into "Embedded View / **Show single category**" which returns the category for the current Person. This way only rows related to this category are visible in embeded view.

Comment: Ok, but I have to explicit add every person to one persons category to filter the documents. Could I use a hidden id field to reference that? Like "Show me all notes documents for current person" and the person document would have an id field for identification?

Comment: Yes, use an id field or a field which combines first and last name.

Comment: There is an option "Choose a View based on a formula". I don't understand what it do. Can I use it?

Comment: No, not in your case. You will use just one certain view which is categorized by person (id or name).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you man! I done the following steps: 1. The Notes View have a first colum set from standard to categorised. The first column displays the value of a field with the ID of the Person. If you look at the not embedded view you see the Notes documents are grouped by this field. 2. Next I set the "show single category" in the embedded view to the field name of the Person Person_ID. And it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an embedded view, you can use a trick I describe here: http://blog.texasswede.com/dynamic-tables-in-classic-notes/

What you do is to build the rows of the view one by one using a separate form, then rendering them into a rich tect field on your person document.